# Login to Facebook using Oauth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0

I set email & pass account in a file php, i want it login automatically when i call the file from browser or comand line, then i get the state for success or failed login, Could you help me, please!

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Use the Facebook PHP SDK to perform the authentication: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/
2. Use the Server side flow outlined in this Reference (the code sample is in PHP) :
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/